# How to edit gltf data in the gltf rust crate?

Tags: animation, rust, graphics, gltf

I am learning rust by writing a terminal utility I need.

This tool needs to take a gltf file and apply a linear transformation to the nodes and to the buffers.

Right now I am trying to scale down the inverse bind matrix data.

To that effect I am using this crate:
https://docs.rs/gltf/latest/gltf/

With the data loaded I am trying reach the binary data like this:

```rust
use gltf::Gltf;

fn main() -> Result<(), gltf::Error>
{
    let gltf = Gltf::open("Assets/werewolf_animated.gltf")?;

    for skin in gltf.skins() {
        for joint in skin.joints()
        {
            println!(
                "Skin #{} has {} joint",
                skin.index(),
                joint.index(),
            );
        }

        for ibm_accessor in skin.inverse_bind_matrices()
        {
            println!("Accessor #{}", ibm_accessor.index());
            println!("offset: {}", ibm_accessor.offset());
            println!("count: {}", ibm_accessor.count());
            println!("data_type: {:?}", ibm_accessor.data_type());
            println!("dimensions: {:?}", ibm_accessor.dimensions());

            println!("buffer: {:?}", ibm_accessor.view().unwrap().buffer().source());
      
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

If this were C or C++ at this stage I would have a float* and I would be able to start reading and writing to the binary data, treating it as a float array. But this is rust.

Any suggestions as to how I can start tampering with the data under `ibm_accessor.view().unwrap().buffer().source()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have never used the glTF data structure or the `glft` crate before. However, I found [this article](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Tutorials/blob/master/gltfTutorial/gltfTutorial_005_BuffersBufferViewsAccessors.md), as well as [this documentation](https://registry.khronos.org/glTF/specs/2.0/glTF-2.0.html#reference-buffer) suggesting that Source data may be encoded as Base64.

Note: [We will need to use the data_url helper library](https://docs.rs/data-url/latest/data_url/)

According to the [documentation](https://docs.rs/gltf/latest/gltf/buffer/enum.Source.html), `Source` is an enum that has two variants: `Bin` and `Uri(&'a str)`.

The idiomatic way of handling the enum would be to match on it:

```rust
// In the import section
use data_url::DataUrl;

// In your code
let source = ibm_accessor.view().unwrap().buffer().source();

match source {
    Bin => {
        // This case seems to only apply to .glb (binary glTF) files.
        // If it doesn't apply, maybe skip it?
        continue;
    },
    Uri(data) => {
        // Here we can handle the data which is of type `&str`
        // As mentioned in the linked documentation, this is
        // probably (?) a `data:` Base64 encoded URI, something like
        // data:application/octet-stream;base64,AAABAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIA/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAPwAAAAA=
        // Mozilla/SimonSapin (well-known Rust dev) wrote this library
        // to handle `data:` URIs: https://docs.rs/data-url/latest/data_url/
        // let's use that.
        let url = match DataUrl::process(data) {
            Ok(url) => url,
            Err(_) => {
                // This is probably not a `data` URI? Maybe it's a https:// link or something? 
                continue;
            }
        };
        
        let (body, _fragment) = match url.decode_to_vec() {
            Ok(res) => res,
            Err(_) => {
                // The base64 was malformed!
                panic!("Or handle this error somehow?");
            }
        };
        // `body` is now a `Vec<u8>` (vector of bytes) which you can loop over.
    }
}
```

## data_url Proof-Of-Concept

Just to prove to myself what the `data_url` crate does, I did this small POC

Carto.toml

```ini
[package]
name = "data-url-test"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
data-url = "0.1.1"
```

main.rs

```rust
use data_url::{DataUrl, mime};

fn main() {
    // URL is from https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Tutorials/blob/master/gltfTutorial/gltfTutorial_005_BuffersBufferViewsAccessors.md
    let data = "data:application/octet-stream;base64,AAABAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIA/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAPwAAAAA=";
    let url = match DataUrl::process(data) {
        Ok(url) => url,
        Err(e) => {
            eprintln!("Error {:#?}", e);
            return;
        }
    };
    let (body, _fragment) = match url.decode_to_vec() {
        Ok(res) => res,
        Err(_) => {
            // The base64 was malformed!
            panic!("Or handle this error somehow?");
        }
    };
    println!("body {:?}", body);
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Some follow up questions, as mentioned the goal is to edit matrices, which means the data needs to be represented as an array of floats rather than bytes, what is the idiomatic way to "cast" or "interpret" a rust vec of bytes as an array of floats?

And the other question is, is this manipulating a copy to the data or the loaded data inside the gltf structure?

Comment: I don't have time right now, but if you ask on https://users.rust-lang.org someone on there will help you, usually very quickly. You can also search on there for "bytes to float" or similar.

Comment: To answer your second question @Makogan I don't think any of this data is "mut" so you can't change it in-place.